# Cannot install angular/cli with npm

Tags: angular, npm-install

I am attempting to install angular cli. I have npm version 5.6.0 and node v8.11.1 installed. Here's what I did in the Command Prompt (admin):

```
justine:~ justine$ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
/Users/justine/.node_modules_global/bin/ng -> /Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

> fsevents@1.1.3 install /Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

[fsevents] Success: "/Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v57-darwin-x64/fse.node" already installed
Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile

> node-sass@4.8.3 install /Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Unable to save binary /Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-57 : { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:885:18)
at sync (/Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
at Function.sync (/Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
at checkAndDownloadBinary (/Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:114:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:157:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path:     '/Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/vendor' }

> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js


> node-sass@4.8.3 postinstall /Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: /usr/local/bin/node /Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
gyp info using node@8.11.1 | darwin | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError (/Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)\n    at F (/Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)\n    at E (/Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)\n    at /Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16\n    at /Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5\n    at /Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python /usr/bin/python
gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version());"` returned: "2.7.10\n"
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 8.11.1
gyp verb command install [ '8.11.1' ]
gyp verb install input version string "8.11.1"
gyp verb install installing version: 8.11.1
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
gyp verb install version is good
gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 8.11.1
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/justine/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.8.3 (node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.8.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

+ @angular/cli@1.7.4
added 993 packages in 34.312s
```

To let you know what I have tried:

- I have uninstalled and deleted angular/cli and run `npm cache verify`
- Attempted to install with npm version 5.7.0

Not sure what to try next. Can you please assist?

Answer (score 0):

Clean cache using `npm cache clean`, uninstall angular-cli `npm uninstall -g angular-cli` and re-install using `npm install -g @angular/cli` or just try force install using `npm install -g -f angular-cli`.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I have run through each of the suggestions you have given, I am getting the same error log (BTW: I needed to do npm cache clean -f). Any further assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems like a problem with your node/npm and not with Angular CLI. Please go through [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) page.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you upgrade your **node** and **npm** versions to latest. After that please follow the below steps to install the **angular/cli:**

1. Open your command prompt with administrative privileges and uninstall **angular/cli** by using **npm uninstall -g angular-cli** command.
2. Remove node_modules directory and then clear the cache by using **npm cache clear --force** command.
3. Remove **C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\  and  C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache.**
   4.Try to install the **angular/cli@latest** by using **npm install -g @angular/cli@latest** command.

Hope the above trick resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I'm on a macbook, can you please confirm which folders I should be deleting? Thanks again

Comment: @JustineVer, please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255269/cant-install-angular-cli-on-mac), you may found the solution.

Comment: Thanks again, I followed your steps 1 and 2 then followed all the steps given in the first solution of the link you referred to. It appears that it was installed the ng -v indicates that Angular is undefined. (and ng new testApp returns 'You cannot use the new command inside an Angular CLI project.' error)

Comment: Sorry, 'You cannot use the new command inside an Angular CLI project.' was due to a package.json file I had in /users/name, deleted it, angular cli appears to be working. Thanks so much for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem. I solved with this:
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm angular-cli