# Installing Angular on Mac OS 10.13

Tags: node.js, angular, macos, npm

I'm trying to follow the [quickstart](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) on running Angular locally (on MacOS 10.13.6). With the first command, I already get some errors:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Output:

```
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/socks
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/socks'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/socks']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/socks\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path:
npm ERR!    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/socks' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/xxx/.npm/_logs/2019-03-12T23_55_12_063Z-debug.log
```

Running with sudo gives me the following:

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents/.node-gyp'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64 --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64 --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
```

My node version is LTS (10.15.3). Any idea what's causing this and how to get angular to run on Mac?

Comment: I literally had this issue yesterday. The node-pre-gyp erros is realted to that npm package that isn't hasnt been fully working for macs. Apps will work fine just be patient for the updated package to come out.

Answer (score 2):

you will need the write permission in node_modules directory:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
```

Running sudo when installing `npm` will give you problems in the long run, so just run the command above.

[npm throws error without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo)

Comment: but I needed to give the write permissions to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

run with sudo permission and you should be good.

Comment: Not sure. I will try to do it on my machine and let you know.

Comment: @Pim  can you try this [Stackover flow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49913107/9958058)

Comment: using sudo isn't good practice. then it will ask you to use sudo every time you install a package. I ran into this issue yesterday

Answer (score 1):

the `/usr/local` folder needs `root` permission, please try install it with `sudo` :

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: using sudo isn't good practice. then it will ask you to use sudo every time you install a package. I ran into this issue yesterday

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, using sudo isn't good practice, I had to run the following 3 commands to gain ownership of the relevant directories:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm  
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib/node_modules
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin
```

Now I can install Angular CLI (or any other node packages) globally, without the need for sudo.