# Mac can't install Angular-CLI

Tags: node.js, macos, ionic-framework, angular-cli

I'm trying to install Angular-CLI so I can use Ionic framework, however the installation keeps crashing and gives me an error as such.

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2019-05-31T09_00_09_770Z-debug.log
```

I've tried installing it by writing

```
sudo npm install -g @angular-cli
```

I've also tried installing it though this method here: 
[Can't install angular-cli on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255269/cant-install-angular-cli-on-mac)

I'm sorry, I'm fairly new to this so I'm unsure on what information I should be providing.

I've installed Node JS (10.16.0)

I've also just installed the Ionic Framework and Cordova, however whenever I try opening a project that I create through the terminal, it tells me that I need to install Angular-CLI and once I say yes to the installation, I receive the same errors as above.

My MacOSX is 10.14.5

EDIT:

I've assigned read and write permission to my current user login on my computer but I'm still getting errors. When I run `Ionic lab` in my terminal to open my project the terminal asks me if I want to install angular and I write Yes. Then I get these errors.

```
[ng] Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "/Users/me/project".
[ng] Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "/Users/me/project".
[ng]     at Object.resolve (/Users/me/project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node/resolve.js:141:11)
[ng]     at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable [as _subscribe] (/Users/me/project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/src/architect-legacy.js:153:40)
[ng]     at Observable._trySubscribe (/Users/me/project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:44:25)
[ng]     at Observable.subscribe (/Users/me/project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:30:22)
[ng]     at /Users/me/project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:99:19
[ng]     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
[ng]     at Observable.toPromise (/Users/me/project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:97:16)
[ng]     at RunCommand.runSingleTarget (/Users/me/project/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:161:86)
[ng]     at RunCommand.runArchitectTarget (/Users/me/project/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:201:35)
[ng]     at RunCommand.run (/Users/me/project/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/run-impl.js:14:25)
[ng]     at RunCommand.validateAndRun (/Users/me/project/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command.js:124:31)
[ng]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[ng]     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:832:11)
[ng]     at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
[ng]     at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

        The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error
        details.
```

Comment: Assign read write permission to /usr/local/lib/node_modules directory and then try agai, (do google how to)

Comment: @Ejaz47 I still get an error. I've edited my question so you can see what type of error I'm getting. Please help

Comment: @Ejaz47 actually thanks to you I think I've figured it out! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If anybody here is running into the same issue as me, basically what I had done was I ran

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm*`

in my terminal and then I restarted me computer. Once I did that I essentially just created a new Project and everything was added from there (including Angular CLI)