# Angular CLI cannot be installed on a Mac computer

Tags: angular, npm, macos-ventura

I'm using a Mac computer which is currently running **macOS Ventura 13.1**

I successfully installed node *(v18.12.1)* & npm *(8.19.2)* on the computer but when I try to run `npm install -g @angular/cli` to install Angular CLI, it gave me the following error.

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

Also, I tried the command with `sudo`, like `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli` , and then it gave me the following error.

```
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
```

I tried installing Angular CLI using `homebrew` and `nvm`, but neither of them succeeded.

Comment: Your path is messed up for global npm I think

Comment: I think you need to set your path up.

Comment: An easier fix is reinstalling npm. use a node version manager for mac: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating

Comment: @devin I tried NVM, but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: I followed this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255269/cant-install-angular-cli-on-mac

It successfully installed NVM. Then I ran the following commands respectively.

`nvm install stable`
`nvm install node`

But when I run `npm install -g @angular/cli`, it gave me the following error.

`npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead`

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I could solve the issue. Here's what I did,

I used homebrew to install Angular CLI via `brew install angular-cli`. Then when I check `ng version`, it showed my current node version (v19) doesn't support for Angular. Then I used Node Version Manager (NVM) to downgrade my node version. I used the below command to install NVM on my Mac (macOS Ventura 13.1).

```bash
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
```

This command automatically updated my `.zshrc` file as well. If it doesn't automatically updated for you, open the `.zshrc` file using `open -t .zshrc` command and add the following code to it.

```bash
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

You can check nvm version using `nvm -v` command.
After that I ran `nvm install 18.12.1` command to downgrade the node version to `18.12.1`.

You can run `node -v` command to verify.

Then I ran `ng version` command and got the following output.

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 15.0.4
Node: 18.12.1
Package Manager: npm 8.19.2
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 
... 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1500.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         15.0.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   15.0.4 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          15.0.4 (cli-only)
```

Then I created my first angular app using `ng new my_first_app` command. It gave me the following error.

```
⠦ Installing packages (npm)...npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: my-first-app@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@undefined
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"^15.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"15.0.4" from @angular/animations@15.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   @angular/animations@"^15.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 

✖ Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

Then I navigated to the project directory and I couldn't see both `node_modules` directory and `package-lock.json` file. Then I tried running the `ng serve` command and it gave me an error and asked me to run `npm install` command. When I run `npm install` command, it didn't work successfully and still I couldn't see `node_modules` directory and `package-lock.json` file inside the angular project.

Finally, I ran the `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` command and it wasn't successful either. Then I ran `sudo npm install --legacy-peer-deps` command and finally it solved the problem.

Then I ran the `ng serve` command and I could get it compiled successfully and see the output on the browser.

Hope this answer will help you when you try to install Angular CLI on macOS Ventura 13.1

Comment: Then I created my second Angular app and it worked smoothly. I didn't have to run `sudo npm install --legacy-peer-deps` command at all. `ng new my_second_app` command created the second angular app and it installed all the packages successfully. All I had to do is just run the `ng serve` command to get my app up and running.

Answer (score 0):

On my macOS Ventura 13.1 using sudo has solved the issue: `sudo ng new my-app`

Comment: This command works, once you successfully installed the Angular CLI. I had an issue with installing Angular CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Using "`sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`"

solved the issue.

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: it works with "sudo npm install -g @angular/cli --force" in my case